# Android - How to draw stroke bitmap?

Tags: android, bitmap, android-canvas, android-bitmap

I have a bitmap like in the picture. I want to add a border for it using Canvas. Can anyone help me?
[image: My bitmap]

Answer (score 0):

You can draw a border using Paint.STYLE.STROKE. You need to do two separate calls to draw.

```
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#BAB399")); // set fill color
canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
    sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);

paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
paint.setStrokeWidth(10); // set stroke width
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff")); // set stroke color
canvas.drawCircle(sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.7f, sbmp.getHeight() / 2+0.7f,
    sbmp.getWidth() / 2+0.1f, paint);
```

Comment: Bro! he said for BItmap. Not Circle or others.

Answer (score 0):

If the image has a transparent background (png file) and the stroke size is not too large, you can just draw the bitmap with a color overlay applied to it 4 times -- left, top, right and bottom.

```java
final float stroke = 20F; //stroke size in pixels.
//Load target image as bitmap.
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inMutable = true;
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.shap, options);
//A new, clear bitmap with same size.
Bitmap newBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
Canvas canvas = new Canvas(newBitmap);
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
//Overlay target bitmap with black color.
PorterDuffColorFilter filter = new PorterDuffColorFilter(Color.BLACK, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
paint.setColorFilter(filter);
//Draw target bitmap over new bitmap.
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, -stroke, 0F, paint); //left
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0F, -stroke, paint); //top
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, stroke, 0F, paint); //right
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0F, stroke, paint); //bottom
//Remove overlay.
paint.setColorFilter(null);
//Draw target bitmap.
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0F, 0F, paint);
//Load new bitmap into ImageView.
ImageView iv = findViewById(R.id.iv);
iv.setImageBitmap(newBitmap);
```

[image]